# vim перестёт отвечать на любые действия

Tags: vim

Через некоторое время работы vim перестаёт отвечать на любые действия. Эмулятор консоли при этом отзывчив. Это точно не `Ctrl+s - Ctrl+q`-прикол и не раскладка. Иногда не реагирует на `SIGHUP`. После удачного `SIGHUP` говорит:

```
Vim: Finished.
Hangup
```

После `kill -9` в консоли отображается несколько введенных в состоянии "конфуза" команд (перемещения, ex-комманды).

```
kkjjjkk:q
```

Перезапуск vim проблему не устраняет. Перезапуск системы - ненадолго, тоже случайная величина.

В чём может быть проблема? Плагины не устанавливал (непосредственно перед этим).

**UPD**.

Вроде помогло раскомментирование строк в `~/vimrc`:

```
map <C-\> :tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
map <A-]> :vsp <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

Но ума не приложу, почему?

**UPD2**.

Видимо, редактирование vimrc косвенно каким-то образом устранило или скрыло проблему. Отсутствует состав проблемы и способ ее изучения.

**UPD3**.

Через некоторое время ошибка вернулась (со старым vimrc). Без него vim работает корректно (см. флаг `-u`). Strace показал, что (в отличие от нормальной работы) присутствует неудачное обращение к `~/vimbak/.swpx`. Создал его, пока полёт нормальный.

Comment: запустите вим в  режиме ингорирования конфига (`vim -u some_non_exists_file` и проверьте, повторяется ли проблема. Если нет - проблема в конфиге. Если да - проблема глубже.

Comment: @KoVadim , спасибо, хороший рецепт. Но после редактирования файла конфигурации ошибка пропала так же неожиданно, как появилась. Даже с вновь закомментированными строками она не появлялась.

Comment: @KoVadim , предложенный вами метод дал плоды! Это какой-то некорректный конфиг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

конечно, если проблема уже не воспроизводится, то о её причинах можно только гадать.

но, возможно, кто-то ещё может столкнуться с подобными симптомами, потому пара рекомендаций:

1. чтобы выяснить, влечёт ли проявление проблемы конфигурация программы, можно вызвать программу с опцией `-u NONE` (см. `:help -u` для подробностей). при этом не будет загружено никаких конфигурационных файлов и плагинов.
2. чтобы выяснить, связано ли проявление проблемы с дисковыми операциями, в операционной системе *gnu/linux* (и, [судя по всему](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strace&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html), в **bsd*) можно воспользоваться такой, например, командой:

   ```
   $ strace -f -e open -o /tmp/какой-нибудь-файл vim
   ```

   в `/tmp/какой-нибудь-файл` будут записываться попытки открытия файлов.

   в *osx* есть примерный аналог — [dtruss](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) (см. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1925978/4827341) и [2](https://superuser.com/q/778458/454489)), который, судя по всему, вызывается примерно так:

   ```
   $ dtruss -f -t open vim 2>/tmp/какой-нибудь-файл
   ```