# Внезапно перестал запускаться SQL Developer и SQL Data Modeler под Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: sql, linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

То есть вчера еще работало а сегодня вдруг перестало. Собственно говоря даже не представляю куда можно смотреть, при запуски из консоли выводит сообщение

```
Custom UI class oracle.bali.ewt.olaf2.OracleLookAndFeel not on classpath.
```

Я не уверен что дело в нем, так как раньше не смотрел то что он выплевывает в консоль....

Я понимаю что исходных данных по сути нет, подскажите куда посмотреть и я их предоставлю

Comment: как-то я задался похожим вопросом (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532490/vim-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F) и получил такое предложение, приведшее к решению в итоге: ``strace -f -e open -o /tmp/logfile programm``. Это позволило отследить, какие файлы открывает программа (и в одной из таких операций была проблема). Возможно, это даст какой-то импульс для решения.

Comment: @LXA ну собственно вот у меня на этой строчках все зависает: +++ exited with 0 +++
11926 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7f9667c47c80} --'11932 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so", O_RDONLY) = 62
11932 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so", O_RDONLY) = 62' -их там много ...

Comment: Мне удалось найти благодаря тому, что сравнивал эти логи с логами нормально работающего приложения. Возможно вам поможет какой-нибудь verbose mode вывести максимально информативный лог. Как бы синхронизировать эти два лога и проверять файлы.

Comment: @LXA проблема в том что второй машинки нет..... хотя сейчас может попробую намутить